# Installing linux OS problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am having a problem about instilling Linux side by side with widows 7. I downloaded the ISO for desktop launched it and now I am at the try before install part when you already boot the dvd. I start the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installer and here's what happens. 1 I choose a language, 2 connect to wifi, 3 click the check marks next to "Download updates while installing" and "Install this thrid-party software. Then I click next and instead of giving me a choice to select whether to install side by side to windows or not is says " This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do? But I do have windows 7 on the computer and it works so how do I fix this problem.

Comment: From the [how-to-ask page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) it recommends that you search for answers already out there.  If I were you, I would have searched "no detected operating systems" and browsed those answers for solutions first.  If your problem persisted, then specify which of those solutions you had already tried and then re-ask your question.  You can specify tags in the search criteria with brackets (e.g. "[system-installation] no detected operating systems" )